# ASP.Net MVC Async File Upload to API with Kendo fails

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, cors

So this Kendo UI Upload worked well when I send files to MVC controller, but I have to change it and send the file directly to API controller, but it fails.

This is the Kendo Upload init code:

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
  async: {
    saveUrl: "@WebApiHelper.GetUrl("Notification/UploadFile")",
    removeUrl: "remove",
    autoUpload: true
  },
  success: function(),
  error: function()
}
```

On Chrome console it shows `Load Canceled` on the Status text of the request in Network tab:

[image]

The result of the request is like shown below:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:45706/api/Notification/UploadFile
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 Ok

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Host:localhost:45706
Origin:http://localhost:1654
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:1654/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
allow-access-from domain:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 03 May 2013 16:53:30 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcR0F0ZWNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXEdBdGVjXE9kaXNzZWlhXEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uXEdBdGVjLkFncm9XZWIuQ29yZVxHQXRlYy5BZ3JvV2ViLkNvcmUuQVBJXGFwaVxOb3RpZmljYXRpb25cVXBsb2FkRmlsZQ==?=
```

Note that the status code is 200 because I returned it in the method. So it reaches the API method...

```
[HttpPost][HttpOptions]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase files)
```

...but the `files` parameter is aways `null`.

This is the CORS related attributes on API webconfig file:

```
<httpProtocol>   
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="allow-access-from domain" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="origin, accept, content-type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />  
  </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

Any thoughts ? Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: your file parameter should be IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files

Comment: This article resolved the CORS problem: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
public ActionResult Document_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Customer obj, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Docs)
        {
                    foreach (var Doc in Docs)
                    {
                        string newFileName = Path.GetFileName(Doc.FileName).Replace(" ",""); //Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(Doc.FileName);
                        var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/"), newFileName);
                        Doc.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                    }
            return Json(new[] { obj }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

Comment: This works for me too, but it have to be used on MVC Front-End level, not in Back-End level, like I want. Am I right?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown what do you mean by MVC front end?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I get your question, check you Route configuration for API controller. This should work with API controllers as well.

Comment: I believe the routes are ok because it stops at a break-point put in the very first line of the method. My application has two projects, one holds only Views(Front-End) and the other holds the Models and Controllers(Back-End). I'm saying that the upload works when I submit to the Controller of the Front-End but when I submit it to the Back-End Controller I have that problem.